# Helvetica Neue Light and Medium fonts on the same page

Tags: html, css, fonts, mobile-browser

Im implementing a responsive website where the normal texts use Helvetica Light and the bold ones use Helvetica Medium
Im using the Helvetica Light as the base font and adding a font weight of 500 for the bold fonts. 
The problem is that, this doesnt work in Android browsers (older). All the fonts show up lighter. If I change it to font-weight:bold, it looks OK in mobile browsers, but in Desktop, the text is very bold.
Is there a way I can fix this, or have abetter way of implementing this.

Comment: using `@media` query you can solve this issue.

Comment: Android browsers generally don’t even have Helvetica at their disposal. You should at least explain how you intend to make browsers use Helvetica when it does not exist in the user’s system.